# how to fix the creases after solidify and why it occurs?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

[image][image]

Currently doing blender sport car creation course in blender 2.8. Followed step by step but also those pixelling after solidify doesn't go.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from one picture and such a vague description. Please edit the question and explain *what* is wrong with it, give your question a meaningful title formed as a question, add more pictures and share the .blend file as well using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Presuming you've added a solidify modifier, it can be due to inverted normals. Try shift+N in edit mode.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sorry i am new to the website, will do fixes as you said

Comment: lemon _ thanks for the comment, yep already added the solidify but it didn't fixed. Also it goes away if i zoom in and shows if i zoom out.

Comment: @suneelgiree if not due to normals, give it a higher thickness. Or as said by Martynas upload your file so that one can have a look.

Comment: @lemon ok. i will increase thickness. I have also uploaded the blend file- https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DBkn8POD

Comment: Have uploaded the file: no issues for me...

Comment: @lemon i am extremely sorry. i send it to you without saving my file been doing it since morning. wait i will upload again

Comment: @lemon i have reuploaded the file - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/bzvnL1er

Comment: ok: don't use two shrinkwrap modifiers this way. Instead of the second one, try a solidify modifier, and so don't model (make faces) for the inner part of the car.

Comment: Please guide me. As per the course, first there is the guide mesh> already one shrinkwrap> then a solidify is added>solidify applied with thickness .003> then another another shrikwrap added for below face with above surface selected and -.003. As per you where should i make changes

Comment: ok, will not be an answer as it could be opinion based. But I think you should model only one side of the car, using one shrinkwrap to the guide then add a solidify modifier to give it some thickness. But visibly, I do not know the entire context of your work and the reason why you attempt to do it this way.

Comment: @lemon - even i don't know mate why i am doing this way, i just followed the course :D

Comment: So... I do not know what to advice... if your teacher wants it so... But in my experience handling two shrinkwraps like that for what's seems to be a retopo is not easy.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

This is [z-fighting](https://www.google.com/search?q=z-fighting&oq). It happens because of binary rounding errors when you have very thin/ overlapping geometry compared to your viewport or camera clipping range. Do not solidify your geometry before using a Shrinkwrap modifier, if you need an edge, use it after Shrinkwrap. Also you do not need all the geometry that is not visible, so you can have rim only:

[image]

You have sides of the surface in vertex groups so I just selected the inner group and deleted it to fix the issue in the screenshot. You could have the Shrinkwrap modifier before solidify there if you needed it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a beginner, can you recommend me tutorial or documentation related to this problem? want to go in details with it. Or maybe i should search up. Thanks

Comment: Sorry just found out you have linked the case

Comment: Sorry, I did not write too much about it, but I think it will be easy enough to find a lot of info about it since it is quite a popular topic. If you have additional questions after a bit of research, please feel free to ask.